# Why Skype doesn't let me log in via MS acc. on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, skype, microsoft

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and loaded Skype from official site. Then went through some instructions on [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/skype-4-3-install-in-ubuntu-1404/) site. 
It works only on my Skype account and when I try to log in via MS account it just returns me on the main screen. What'swrong with it? Why MS doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too faced this problem for one of our users. `Microsoft` has updated their terms and conditions. Please try login to  your account in
[Microsoft](https://login.live.com/) website. `Accept` the updated terms and conditions and then try login to `Skype` using `Microsoft` account.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you accept this as the answer to your question, kindly click on the `tick` mark on the left hand side so that it become green and do up vote by clicking the up arrow (This answer is helpful). Thanks